# HTML 5 Video not loading from url (Chrome only)

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, video

I have the following code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 

     Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

And its working fine from local files, but when i try

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="URL" type="video/mp4"> 

     Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

It loads the video frame and buttons, but i cant start it. Also all buttons are inactive. This happens in Chrome only. I tryed using autorun, but its not starting(again it works in FF, but not in Chrome)

**Edit** location/id is the download link for the video.
There is a console error that cames up after 1 min: GET location/id net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

**Edit 2** I dont think that i am allowed to post the real location. This is the code fragment that i am using for testing:

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls="">              
        <source src="test video.mp4" > </source>                       
    </video>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls="">              
            <source src="URL" type="video/mp4">   </source> <-- this is the one that is not running          
        </video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="">              
            <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <--for testing  </source>               

</video>
```

**URL** and **test video.mp** are the same file, ran from url and localy, the third video is for testing and its working. The thing is - *URL* gives me the download address, but when i open *http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4* the video runs on another tab. Is it possible that i have wrong url (dont forget that everything runs on FF)
URL is the download link for the file ?

Comment: Any error message in console?

Comment: Nope. There are also no errors in the video box itself

Comment: Also no console errors

Comment: I am sorry there is a console error it just cames up after 1 min:
GET location/id net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: In that case you might be having a connection problem with the location. Firefox work probably because you used Firefox to download the video before so it's reading the cache.

Comment: I am pretty sure that i downloaded it with Chrome. Anyway i just re-downloaded it with Chrome and its still not working.

Comment: Is your mp4 file on a streaming server? probably wowza or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different flavours of MP4 video, so perhaps yours is not the right one for Chrome to play, even though Firefox can play it.

Perhaps you could try re-converting it using something like [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)?

Comment: yeah i thought the same, but as i said i can run the SAME file if its on my hard drive

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I missed that you had said that it works locally. The only other thing would be that the location is wrong, but again you said that it works on Firefox so that's odd too. Do you have a link to the actual code where it's not working so I could have a look?

Comment: Ok I see. Wiat though, what is 'location/id'? That's not a valid file location...it's never going to work.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a server side issue where your MP4 are hosted. You could take the following steps:

- Check you have CORS enabled on your server and you are using a recent version of Chrome. More on enabling CORS: http://enable-cors.org
- Check your mime/type for MP4 are in order on your apache/nginx/(or else) server see section [server support here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)
- Try hosting the file on another remote server
- Try in Safari desktop/Internet explorer 9+ to see if you can read the file (both can read mp4 files in HTML5)
- Add the codecs info in your source tag `<source src="URL" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"' />`

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET seems to indicate a network error/timeout. Are you using a proxy between where you test and where is the mp4 file hosted?

Thanks